# quantiles (monotonic transformation)

Tags: mathematical-statistics, quantiles, order-statistics

I'm trying to show that, $(-X)_p = -X_{(1-p)}$, that is, the $p$ quantile of $-X$ is equal to the $1-p$ quantile of $X$ after multiplying with $-1$. The results holds when considering quantiles of a continuous distribution.

I'm assuming Type 6 quantiles (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile#Estimating_quantiles_from_a_sample). We define $h= p(n+1)$, $k=[h], r=h-[h]$. Then the quantile is $X_p = (1-r)X_{(k)} + rX_{(k+1)}$.

$$ (-X)_p = ( (1-r)(-X)_{(k)}+r(-X)_{(k+1)} )$$

We use the fact that $(-X)_{(k)} = -X_{(n-k+1)}$, since we simply reversed the order of the ranks. Then,

$$ (-X)_p = -( (1-r)X_{(n-k+1)}+rX_{(n-k)} ). $$

Implying that the  $(1-r)X_{(n-k+1)}+rX_{(n-k)} $ should equal $X_{1-p}$, but that does not hold, for $X_{1-p}$ the parameters are $h^* = n+1-h, k^* = n-k+1, r^* = -r$, leading us to

$$X_{1-p} = (1+r)X_{(n-k+1)} - rX_{(n-k+2)}. $$

What am I doing wrong?